# SSMS Pivot table/Unduplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get these four lines to combine into 1 line and remove any duplicated usernames so the users only show up once.

```
select 
    z.location
    , z.name 
    , a.name 
    , b.name 
    , c.name 
    , d.name 
    , e.name 
    , f.name 
    , g.name
from z
left join a on z.managerid = a.employeeid
left join b on a.managerid = b.employeeid
left join c on b.managerid = c.employeeid
left join d on c.managerid = d.employeeid
left join e on d.managerid = e.employeeid
left join f on e.managerid = f.employeeid
left join g on f.managerid = g.employeeid
```

My current output is:

[image: here]

My end goal is to end up with one line for the location with all the necessary names still only in one line (preferably unduplicated).

Comment: Please add your current output as formatted text, and show us your query.

Comment: Please include the sample data and the expected output as text. Please avoid using image